# equivalent definitions of recursively enumerable sets

Tags: computability, recursion

In some textbooks, a n-ary set R is defined as r.e iff there's it is a domain of a recursive function.

In others, definition is restricted to case n=1 and a set is called r.e. if it is a range of recursive function.

I wonder definition by range case can be exteneded to any n-ary set.

Comment: One could say that a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}^n$ is r.e. if $\{f(x)\;\vert\;x\in X\}$ is r.e., where $f:\mathbb{N}^n\to\mathbb{N}$ is a recursive bijection?

Comment: There is a computable bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^n$, so the $n$ doesn't matter. In $n=1$, you can prove that a set is the domain of a (partial) recursive function iff it's the range of a (partial) recursive function.